# Can I get the "Use Item" achievement in Groove Coaster without paying money?

Tags: groove-coaster

Taito's *Groove Coaster* for iOS has an achievement called "Use Item" which you get for simply using an item on a level. Items are expendable powerups that make levels slightly easier.

Items are available for purchase in the Upgrade menu of the game for $0.99 for 10.

Is there any way to acquire an item, thereby allowing the achievement, without buying some in the Upgrade shop?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. Many avatars can be unlocked or upgraded by completing levels, but items are only available through in-app purchase.